# Google Analytics - Tracking No Match Search Queries on Site

Tags: google-analytics

We are trying to track every time a "No Matches found" result is returned for users using our site search. We set up a custom metric and placed the code within the search iframe but we are not seeing any data. Any ideas on why the data is not populating?

Comment: We'll need more info about how your site is setup- how is the iframe involved specifically? You should post the code you're referring to because it could be any number of things.

Comment: Are you using Google Tag Manager or the Google Analytics library?

Comment: Did you set up the custom metric in the GA Interface?